# customize progress bar with Gif image not work fine on some devices

Tags: android, progress-bar, gif

My progress bar not working as expected on some devices [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOGVu.jpg) and working as expected [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rxt9.png) and this is [original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtkwt.gif)

of

if anyone have better idea of use gif file on progress bar please share with me.

.java

```
public static void displayProgressDialog(Context context, boolean cancellable) {
    ImageView imageView;

    if (context == null || (context instanceof AppCompatActivity && ((AppCompatActivity) context).isFinishing()))
        return;
    if (cancellable) {
        if (context instanceof AppCompatActivity && view == null) {
            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) context;
            view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog_loading, null);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            activity.addContentView(view, params);
        }
    } else {
        if (progressDialog != null) return;
        progressDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyTheme).create();
        FrameLayout f1 = new FrameLayout(context);
        progressDialog.setView(f1);
        progressDialog.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog_loading, f1);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
//        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
//        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/bgColorDefault"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/myprogress_interminate"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

rotation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/animation"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

finally here animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinnerinstacare">
</rotate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First create a better GIF**

> If you want to show `GIF` inside a `custom dialog` at the center of
>   the screen use below code:

Use this Static Method:

```
public static void showProgress(Context context) {  
    Dialog progressDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.AppThemeDialog);
    progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progers_layout);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = progressDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
    wmlp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    wmlp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

Progress layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_anim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use Glide like this:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.raw.image_gif).into(imageView);
```

Then you can use `Glide` to load `GIF`.

Comment: where is Class GlideDrawableImageViewTarget !
how to import it?

Comment: Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because on some devices could be changed `attrs` for default system width and height. Which could effect some of the widgets like `ProgressBar`. You need to specify exact size of the item in layout.

Or just use `ImageView` with `Glide` to show gif, during loading, with very easy setup.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
}
```

And usage:

```
Glide.with(context).load(GIF_URI)
    .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(IMAGE_VIEW));
```

Comment: GlideDrawableImageViewTarget where is this class?